# Cell-Free massive mimo for satellite communication design

Tags: communication-satellite

I am interested in LEO satellite communication and its integration into a 5g terrestrial network. Cell-free massive mimo (CFmMIMO) is a concept used in 5G design. It looks, CFmMIMO can be used if we design UL (terrestrial-to-satellite). As I understood, in this case, satellites are access points.

I am thinking if I can design a DL link, where the terrestrial network is an access point, and the satellite is the “user”?

PS is it the right community for my question?

Comment: This is not off-topic per se, but I don't think you'll get great answers here, as it requires much more knowledge about the inner workings of the 5g network than that of satellites. For the space part: your "user" is traveling at 8km/s and is never closer to the base station than some 150km, (about the lowest reasonable LEO altitude; more preferably 200-400km). You sure can put any electronics you want on the satellite, and keep any antenna aimed precisely at any point on Earth you want, and from that point on this becomes purely a 5g network question.